# Can we Implement Malloc function without use of brk() system call

Tags: c, malloc

Is it possible to implement the `malloc` library function without using `brk`? Can I use `sbrk(0)` to find out the current position of the program break, and then use `sbrk(size)` to increment it?

If yes, then why was `brk` added in the first place?

Comment: Since you mention `brk` and `sbrk` I assume you're on a UNIX (or UNIX-like) system? Then you can use anonymous ["file" mapping](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to accomplish something similar.

Comment: Similarly, `malloc(n)` can be implemented by `realloc(0, n)`. That does not mean that `malloc()` is useless.

Answer (score 4):

The use of `brk` and `sbrk` is discouraged in most current Unixes. Instead, `malloc` typically calls `mmap` anonymously (without file backing), and the address of a page is returned.

`brk` and `sbrk` assume a contiguous address space, which is no longer the case. Nowadays, a process may have many mappings in different ranges, with unmapped gaps in between.

The POSIX standard also warns us that:

> The behaviour of brk() and sbrk() is unspecified if an application also uses any other 
>   memory functions (such as malloc(), mmap(), free()). Other functions may use these other memory functions silently.